# Is it possible to load part of a trained model into part of a newly built model in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

Is it possible to load part of a trained model into part of a newly built model in TensorFlow?

I mean, for instance, some formerly trained model of no use. But part of it is still useful. And that part could be used in a newly built model. Except this part, others of the newly built model should be trained, but this part need not be retrained again. And the newly built model is quite different from the old model except that part is the same.

If this could be done, how to write such code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the possibilities:

- Get the code for the model you are importing
- Find the last operation of the part of the graph that you want to keep
- Split the code into two parts (classes or functions) at this op
- Build the shared part of the graph and load the weights
- Proceed adding the rest of the new graph
- Run the terminal op in the newly added part

Alternatively, you may build the entire old model, have a "fork" in the middle and, when running, ignore the terminal op in the old, unused part, and use only the terminal op in the newly added part. This way, only the new branch will be trained.

If you don't have the code but only have the saved graph definition, it is a bit more complicated: you will need to find the op you want to fork in the loaded graph by name.

Comment: I have the code of building the old model. How to write such a "fork" code? Could you please give an example?

Comment: @Drop In general case, use output(s) of the last op of the shared code as input(s) of the first op of the new code

Comment: Why do they give me negative feedback? I think my question is at least somewhat useful.